# Картинки и JSON

Tags: android, json, изображения

Задача такая: нужно организовать оборот картинок(аватарки) для профайла. В REST проекте на Android.  Дилемма в том какой путь выбрать : 1) Отправлять картинки в JSON в виде строки (в обоих направлениях сервер-android); 
2)В JSON`e отправлять только адреса картинок , а грузить их уже отдельными URL запросами.
Хочется знать мнение профи что предпочтительней ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать картинку текстом - плохая идея. Чем меньше информации передаётся - тем лучше.

Засим, передавайте URL картинки и грузите её отдельно.